# create a chart bar in vue.js + bulma

Tags: vue.js, bulma

so iam doing front-end with vue.js and bulma. As you can see by this far, there was a line chart in home page. [image: linechart]. The code in home.vue template is gonna be like this :

```
<line-chart style="height: 100%"
                      ref="bigChart"
                      chart-id="big-line-chart"
                      :chart-data="defaultChart.chartData"
                      :extra-options="defaultChart.extraOptions">
</line-chart>
```

also we have the script in the home.vue :

```
methods: {
    randomChartData (n) {
      const data = []

      for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        data.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 200))
      }

      return data
    },
    fillChartData () {
      this.defaultChart.chartData = {
        datasets: [
          {
            fill: false,
            borderColor: chartConfig.chartColors.default.primary,
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderDash: [],
            borderDashOffset: 0.0,
            pointBackgroundColor: chartConfig.chartColors.default.primary,
            pointBorderColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: chartConfig.chartColors.default.primary,
            pointBorderWidth: 20,
            pointHoverRadius: 4,
            pointHoverBorderWidth: 15,
            pointRadius: 4,
            data: this.randomChartData(9)
          },
          {
            fill: false,
            borderColor: chartConfig.chartColors.default.info,
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderDash: [],
            borderDashOffset: 0.0,
            pointBackgroundColor: chartConfig.chartColors.default.info,
            pointBorderColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: chartConfig.chartColors.default.info,
            pointBorderWidth: 20,
            pointHoverRadius: 4,
            pointHoverBorderWidth: 15,
            pointRadius: 4,
            data: this.randomChartData(9)
          }
        ],
        labels: ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09']
      }
    }
  }
```

the 2nd code is inisiating the random data to fulfill the linechart. So i have this linechart buy installing vue js chart. What did i want to ask is about how i can created bar chart version of this ??

I already created a bar chart but the bar chart didnt seems to be appeared in home page, why ??

```
<bar-chart style="height: 100%"
                      ref="bigChart"
                      chart-id="big-line-chart"
                      :chart-data="defaultChart.chartData"
                      :extra-options="defaultChart.extraOptions">
          </bar-chart>
```

For the extra, i add the linechart.js :

```
import { Line, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'

export default {
  name: 'line-chart',
  extends: Line,
  mixins: [mixins.reactiveProp],
  props: {
    extraOptions: Object
  },
  data () {
    return {
      ctx: null
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.$watch('chartData', (newVal, oldVal) => {
      if (!oldVal) {
        this.renderChart(
          this.chartData,
          this.extraOptions
        )
      }
    }, { immediate: true })
  }
}
```

and this is bar chart.js

```
import { Bar, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'

export default {
  name: 'bar-chart',
  extends: Line,
  mixins: [mixins.reactiveProp],
  props: {
    extraOptions: Object
  },
  data () {
    return {
      ctx: null
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.$watch('chartData', (newVal, oldVal) => {
      if (!oldVal) {
        this.renderChart(
          this.chartData,
          this.extraOptions
        )
      }
    }, { immediate: true })
  }
}
```